# Static content with Maven Jetty Plugin

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

How can I serve static content with maven jetty plugin (7.x)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have such a configuration at my jetty.xml. I have just wanted to updated my question.

```
 <Set name="handler">
     <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList">
        <Set name="handlers">
           <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
              <Item>
                 <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler">
                    <Set name="contextPath">/static</Set>
                    <Set name="resourceBase">${static-resources-path}</Set>
                    <Call name="addServlet">
                       <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</Arg>
                       <Arg>/</Arg>
                    </Call>
                 </New>
              </Item>
           </Array>
        </Set>
     </New>
  </Set>
```

Answer (score 3):

put your static contents under any folder below `/yourStaticApp/src/main/webapp` -- say under `/yourStaticApp/src/main/webapp/static`. When you will run Jetty these will be available as `http://host:port/contextRoot/static/fileName.ext`

---

Hmmm, unsure, if that's possible. Eclipse Jetty Maven plugin documents a way to configure static source location, which boils down to the alternate location of `webapps` mentioned above.

```
 ...
 <plugin>
    ...
    <configuration>
      <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/staticfiles</webAppSourceDirectory>
      ...
    </configuration>
    ...
  </plugin>
  ...
```

As the doc points out:

> **<webAppSourceDirectory>**–By default, this is set to ${basedir}/src/main/webapp. If your static sources are in a different location, set this parameter accordingly.

refer: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin

---

**Update:** On some more reseach I found out that you can actually point the location of `webdefault.xml` from in Jetty-maven plugin; and in webdefault.xml you can configure the *static content* location.

In your Jetty Maven configuration, point the location of wendefault.xml

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     ...
      <defaultsDescriptor>/my/path/to/webdefault.xml</defaultsDescriptor>
     ...
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Now, with `webdefault.xml` in your hand you can put the configuration mentioned here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Static+Content -- except the package Names has been changed from `org.mortbay.jetty...` to `org.eclipse.jetty...` see below:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Context">
  <Set name="contextPath">/javadoc</Set>
  <Set name="resourceBase"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/javadoc/</Set>
  <Call name="addServlet">
    <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</Arg>
    <Arg>/</Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

refer: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/webdefault.xml

I haven't tested/used the above. But let me know, if you get this working. Or if anything else needed to get this done.

Comment: I dont mean this. I mean a directory to serve as a static content. Check this please. I wanted such a solution with maven. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Static+Content

Comment: it did not help me. I am sure there is something else to configure. But I mostly interested in second solution at that page. IS this possible to configure in pom.xml like this http://blog.markfeeney.com/2009/12/scala-lift-jetty-6-static-content-and.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a config which works for me, using the resourceBase and contextPath values on the  JettyWebAppContext

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.7.v20170914</version>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>60</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/app</contextPath>
        </webApp>
        <contextHandlers>
            <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
                <contextPath>/images</contextPath>
                <resourceBase>./../../env/localhost/config/images</resourceBase>
            </contextHandler>
        </contextHandlers>
```